# expression must have pointer-to-object type?

Tags: c++

I made this simple function to check if a day is "valid".

```
void check_day() // Check if the day is valid
{

    bool legal_day = false;

    for(size_t i=0; i < legal_days.size(); ++i)
    {
       if (days[i] == legal_day[i])
        legal_day = true;

       if (i == legal_days.size()-1 && legal_day == false)
        days[i] = "rejected";
   }
}
```

However, it complains about this line: `if (days[i] == legal_day[i])` (the second i)
Is there a way to get around this problem or will I have to rewrite a little?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the declarations of both `days` and `legal_days`.

Comment: there's a typo it should be `if (days[i] == legal_days[i])`

Comment: `legal_day` is a `bool`, yet you are indexing it: `legal_day[i]`. You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`legal_day` is of type `bool` and you are indexing it like : `legal_day[i]` but this is not correct.

It seems that it's a typo... Fix it by doing :

```
if (days[i] == legal_days[i])
    //                  ^
```

I guess you wanted to use `legal_days` who seems to be a container like a `std::vector`.

Comment: Oh wow, it was just a silly typo (can't believe I didn't notice), thanks :P